# Sanitize / Validate Kivy Settings User Input

Tags: python, validation, kivy, settings

If you use the ConfigParser/Settings provided by Kivy and add your own settings defined in json, then you only have two types of settings which are secure: "type": "options" and "type": "bool". The reason is, that the other types will give the user a textinput widget, where they can possibly enter anything they like. E.g. `import os; os.system("rm -r ~")`. However, a given setting may have many different values (actually I am dealing with a setting, which has many different possible values). So I cannot use the only two secure types, because it would blow the screen.

So I digged into the ConfigParser and Settings classes on github and I found `config.add_callback`. You have access to your config object in the `build` method, so I went into that method and added `self.config.add_callback(self.validate_settings_input)`. The callback function that you add, will get all the parameters that `on_config_change` gets, except for the first one (`config`). So I added my validation code to `self.validate_settings_input`. In case user input is not valid, I want to override it, so I added `self.config.set('MySection', 'MyKey', override_value)` and `config.write()`. But this does not work, or at least it does not work as I expect it to work:

For the following description, note that there exists a class attribute which is set to the value of the setting (the wiring is in `on_config_change`). If you click on the setting, the popup with the textinput pops up. If you type in a valid value and submit with OK, then the setting is changed (in the config file, in the Settings-GUI and in the programm/class). If, however, you type in a non-valid value, then the setting is also changed (in the config file, in the Settings-GUI, but not in the programm/class). If you then close the app and start it again, then the setting will be changed to a valid value, as defined in self.validate_settings_input.

So the only case, where my validation is done correctly, is `on_start()`. Although callbacks added to `ConfigParser` using `add_callback` should get called every time `config.set()` is called. And without knowing I assume that `config.set()` is called even when the user changes a setting via the GUI. If not, what sense does this all make?

Googleing "Kivy input validation" yields only one stackoverflow question, which has no answer. Also that question is about normal textinput widgets. However, the textinput widget I am concerned with, is an internal object of some Settings class.

Do you have any suggestions how to sanitize/validate the user input to settings?

### Example Code

```
###############################################################################
# Version
###############################################################################

__version__ = '0.1'



###############################################################################
# Imports
###############################################################################


# Python build-in Modules
from functools import partial   # schedule callback functions that take arguments different from 'dt'

# Kivy
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, StringProperty

from kivy.uix.settings import SettingsWithTabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.logger import Logger




###############################################################################
# Constants
###############################################################################

BACKGROUND_COLOR = [0,0,0,0]
TEXT_COLOR = [1,1,1,1]


JSON_MATH = '''
[
    {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Operator (free choice)",
        "desc": "Choose the operator. + (addition). - (subtraction). * (multiplication). : (division). % (modulo). You can also choose any combination of those operations to create your own mix.",
        "section": "Math",
        "key": "operator"
    },
    {
        "type": "options",
        "title": "Operator (options)",
        "desc": "Choose the operator. + (addition). - (subtraction). * (multiplication). : (division). % (modulo). You can also choose from three mixes.",
        "options": ["+", "-", "*", ":", "%", "+-", "*:", "+-*:"],
        "section": "Math",
        "key": "operator_"
    }
]
'''

kv_string = """
<MySettingsRoot>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Label:
        text: '[b] My Settings App [/b]'
        markup: True

    Button:
        text: 'Settings'
        on_release: app.open_settings()

    Button:
        text: 'Quit'   
        on_release: app.stop()
"""



###############################################################################
# Widgets
###############################################################################




###############################################################################
# Root Widget
###############################################################################

class MySettingsRoot(BoxLayout):
    """ See kv string
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySettingsRoot, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def changeScreen(self, next_screen):
        pass    

    def onBackBtnPress(self):
        pass



###############################################################################
# App Object
###############################################################################

class MySettingsApp(App):
    """ App object
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySettingsApp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.use_kivy_settings = False
        self.settings_cls = SettingsWithTabbedPanel         

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv_string)
        self.config.add_callback(self.config_input_validation)
        return MySettingsRoot()

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('Math', {'operator': '+-:%', 'operator_': '*'})

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel('Math', self.config, data=JSON_MATH)

    def config_input_validation(self, section, key, value, *args):
        """ Callback function, which is bound to the same event as on_config_change.
            It is supposed to validate the value that a user sets some setting to.
            It is being called, but config.set and config.write just don't work.

            However, if the app is restartet, all settings that are not valid, are 
            changed to valid values. This is realy wired!
        """       

        if section == 'Math':
            if key == 'operator':

                if set(["+", "-", "*", ":", "%"]).union([str(v) for v in value]) != set(["+", "-", "*", ":", "%"]):
                    Logger.info('App: This choice is forbidden. Returning to default.')
                    self.config.set('Math', 'operator', '*')
                    self.config.write()

                    # Also tried combinations of the following lines:
                    #Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.config.set, 'Math', 'diffclty', value))   # -> set-method misses *args, so dt cannot be catched
                    #self.config.write()
                    #Clock.schedule_once(self.close_settings)
                    #Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.on_config_change, self.config, 'Math', 'diffclty', value))
                    #Clock.schedule_once(self.open_settings, 1)

            if key == 'operator_':
                pass


    def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value, *args):

        if section == 'Math':

            if key == 'operator':

                Logger.info('App: Your operators via free choice: %s' %value)
                #self.root.calculation_screen.operation = ''.join([str(MathBackEnd.operator_strings.index(p)) for p in list(value)])                

            if key == 'operator_':

                Logger.info('App: Your operators via options: %s' %value)




if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    MySettingsApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to subclass `Settings` and `SettingString`, both found in the kivy [API](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/settings.py) for settings. In the subclass of `SettingString`, define a method `_validate` containing the validation. The user input will be saved in `self.textinput.text`, a valid value should be saved in `self.value` and a non-valid value just ends the process (or raises an exception). In the subclass of `Settings` register a new type and set it to your subclass of `SettingString`. This type is to be used in the json file, when defining the data for the setting.

```
# Kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

from kivy.uix.settings import Settings
from kivy.uix.settings import SettingString
from kivy.uix.settings import InterfaceWithNoMenu
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.logger import Logger





JSON_MATH = '''
[
    {
        "type": "complex_operator_string",
        "title": "Operator (free choice)",
        "desc": "Choose the operator. + (addition). - (subtraction). * (multiplication). : (division). % (modulo). You can also choose any combination of those operations to create your own mix.",
        "section": "Math",
        "key": "operator"
    },
    {
        "type": "options",
        "title": "Operator (options)",
        "desc": "Choose the operator. + (addition). - (subtraction). * (multiplication). : (division). % (modulo). You can also choose from three mixes.",
        "options": ["+", "-", "*", ":", "%", "+-", "*:", "+-*:"],
        "section": "Math",
        "key": "operator_"
    }
]
'''

kv_string = """
<MySettingsRoot>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Label:
        text: '[b] My Settings App [/b]'
        markup: True

    Button:
        text: 'Settings'
        on_release: app.open_settings()

    Button:
        text: 'Quit'   
        on_release: app.stop()

<ValidatedSettings>:
    interface_cls: 'ValidatedSettingsInterface'
"""



###############################################################################
# Widgets
###############################################################################

class ValidatedSettingsInterface(InterfaceWithNoMenu):  
    pass

class ValidatedSettings(Settings):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ValidatedSettings, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_type('complex_operator_string', OperatorSetting)

    def add_kivy_panel(self):
        pass

class OperatorSetting(SettingString):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(OperatorSetting, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def _validate(self, instance):
        self._dismiss()    # closes the popup
        try:
            assert set(["+", "-", "*", ":", "%"]).union([str(v) for v in self.textinput.text]) == set(["+", "-", "*", ":", "%"])
            self.value = self.textinput.text
            Logger.info('App: Assertion is true, setting value to textinput')
        except AssertionError:
            Logger.info('App: This choice is forbidden.')
            return



###############################################################################
# Root Widget
###############################################################################

class MySettingsRoot(BoxLayout):
    """ See kv string
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySettingsRoot, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)




###############################################################################
# App Object
###############################################################################

class MySettingsApp(App):
    """ App object
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySettingsApp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.settings_cls = ValidatedSettings         

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv_string)
        return MySettingsRoot()

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('Math', {'operator': '+-:%', 'operator_': '*'})

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel('Math', self.config, data=JSON_MATH)



    def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value, *args):

        if section == 'Math':

            if key == 'operator':

                Logger.info('App: Your operators via free choice: %s' %value)

            if key == 'operator_':

                Logger.info('App: Your operators via options: %s' %value)




if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    MySettingsApp().run()
```